# Django Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: python, django, admin

I am at my wits.  I am trying to set up Django admin but I am having a hard time.  I have followed the Django book and checked several times but get an invalid syntax (urls.py, line 23).

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import hello, current_datetime, hours_ahead

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^hello/$', hello),
    (r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    (r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls), 
)
```

Any insight would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing parens on line 22:

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

When you get a `SyntaxError` in Python, check that your parenthesis are balanced on the lines preceding it.