# Django 3 invalid syntax in models.py on FileField Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting invalid syntax (, line 15) pylint(syntax-error) [15,6] which is preventing me from making migrations. Was working before I added a few fields that one was working before.

It had previously worked.

I added the [model class choices using named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/)  to group the meteorites instead of inherited classes which people say causes issues from what I read. Could find anything in it that could cause it but still a possibility.

I have tried deleting and reformatting it to see if the indentation was off nothing working. This usually fixes issues for me.

i also tried this stackoverflow result [Adding ImageField to model causes exception in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352117/adding-imagefield-to-model-causes-exception-in-django)

But I had pillow already installed and the unicode part did not make a difference.

I also checked to see if [my parenthesis are balanced][1] which I believe they are but was a stackoverflow result.
.
I added the default to everything so i can makemigrations last time this worked and i made migrations and added a example.

```
default='')
```

it saying its this line  below

```
    main_image=models.FileField(upload_to='media/', default='')
```

**blog/models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone


    class Post(models.Model):
        CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('iron meteorites', 'iron meteorites'),
        ('stony meteorites', 'stony meteorites'),
        ('stony-iron meteorites', (
            ('pallasite', 'pallasite'),
            ('mesosiderites', 'mesosiderites'),
            ),
        )

        main_image=models.FileField(upload_to='media/', default='')
        second_image=models.FileField(upload_to='media/', default='')
        arthor=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        title=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        description=models.TextField(default='')
        more_info=models.TextField(default='')
        l_heading=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        l_heading_text=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        qoute=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        qoute_name=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        s_heading=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        s_heading_text=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        category=models.CharField(
            max_length=256, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='')
        created_date=models.DateTimeField(default='')
        text=models.TextField(default='')
        tag_1=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        tag_2=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')
        tag_3=models.CharField(max_length=256, default='')

        class Meta:
            ordering=['-created_date']
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565099/django-invalid-syntax-error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `),`
As simple as this:

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('iron meteorites', 'iron meteorites'),
    ('stony meteorites', 'stony meteorites'),
    ('stony-iron meteorites', (
        ('pallasite', 'pallasite'),
        ('mesosiderites', 'mesosiderites'),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I already fixed as above with a extra ), and I changed the ( to [ and added the default field

Answer (score 0):

I found it i needed to change this

```
  class Post(models.Model):
        CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('iron meteorites', 'iron meteorites'),
        ('stony meteorites', 'stony meteorites'),
        ('stony-iron meteorites', (
            ('pallasite', 'pallasite'),
            ('mesosiderites', 'mesosiderites'),
            ),
        )
```

into this

```
class Post(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
    ('iron meteorites', 'iron meteorites'),
    ('stony meteorites', 'stony meteorites'),
    ('stony-iron meteorites', (
        ('pallasite', 'pallasite'),
        ('mesosiderites', 'mesosiderites'),
        ),
    ),
    ]
```

i also add a default for the category as well.

```
 category=models.CharField(
        max_length=256, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='stony meteorites')
```

I noticed they did this way in the documents using YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [ to start instead of a YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one parenthesis too many for the CATEGORY_CHOICES variable where `('pallasite', 'pallasite')` is. Or you missed to close this parenthese...